# Filter already created O2M field records on the basis of a field on button click in ODOO

Tags: odoo-8

I have a one2many field like:

```
pricelist_details = fields.One2many('price.list.details', 'price_list_id', string='Price List Details', copy=True)
```

and xml like:

```
<notebook>
    <page>
        <field name="pricelist_details" nolabel="1" widget="one2many_list">
            <tree string="Price List Details" editable="bottom" create="false">
                <field name="state" invisible="1"></field>
                <field name="date_time" attrs="{'required': True, 'readonly': True}"></field>
                <field name="company_id" attrs="{'required': True, 'readonly': True}"></field>
                <field name="category_id" attrs="{'required': True, 'readonly': True}"></field>
                <field name="grade" attrs="{'required': True, 'readonly': True}"></field>
                <field name="ex_mill" attrs="{'required': True, 'readonly': True}"></field>
                <field name="sale_price_per_lb" attrs="{'required': True, 'readonly': [('state', '!=', 'draft')]}"></field>
                <field name="price_per_bag" attrs="{'required': True, 'readonly': True}"></field>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </page>
</notebook>
```

On a button click all the records are created and show up on GUI for this field.
Now i have added some filter fields beside this field like:

```
minor = fields.Many2one('product.minor',string='Minor')
sub_category = fields.Many2one('product.subcategory', string='Sub Category')
```

What i want is to filter my one2many field records on the basis of these filters. I dont want any records to be deleted. Just have 
to filter the records.
Please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Write the onchange method of the field "sub_category" and populate the response as you want it to be. return statement should looks like below:

```
return {'values': {'pricelist_details': [record_set]}}
```

**record_set** contains the objects that are filtered as per the field sub_category

**record_set** will be populated as below:

```
records_set = self.env['product.category'].search([('sub_category', '=', ID)])
```

NOTE: ID is the id of the changed field whose onchange method you are writing.